# Wget skips the download saying 'not modified on server. Omitting download' even thought I have deleted the file from my directory

Tags: bash, wget

I am using wget to download satellite data from NASA, originally I had downloaded some of them but had mixed up directories so deleted all of the files. I have now fixed the bash file so that for each month it saves into the correct directory.
Bash file:

```
filename=./data_full.csv

while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo downloading $line
    wget -e robots=off -m -np -R .html,.tmp -nH --cut-dirs=3 "$line" --header "Authorization: Bearer **AUTHENICATION KEY**" -P /Downloads/2015/Monthly/April
done < "$filename"
```

Where the filename data_full.csv is a list of the URL's I need to download.

However, when I run this bash script now it says:

```
--2020-04-18 11:25:23--  https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A1/2015/099/VNP46A1.A2015099.h30v05.001.2019143192520.h5
Resolving ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov (ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov)... 2001:4d0:241a:40c0::40, 198.118.194.40
Connecting to ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov (ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov)|2001:4d0:241a:40c0::40|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified
File ‘/Downloads/2015/Monthly/April/VNP46A1/2015/099/VNP46A1.A2015099.h30v05.001.2019143192520.h5’ not modified on server. Omitting download.
```

Even though the file has been deleted.
How do I make sure that wget downloads all the files in the .csv

I have used a different authentication code but that also did not work.